Segment Chatlog into chunks
I have a dataset of Chat logs for classification. Basically I need to process this Chatlog into chunks of chats talking about a specific topic. Like this
Bob: What kind of movie would you like
Lara: Nothing Violent please
Bob: How about the new Tarantino Flick?
<Chunk End>
Lara: Did you remember Mom's birthday?
Bob: Yeah sure, that's why I bought her a pack of chips
<Chunk End>
Lara: This isn't working out
...

Whats a good way to do this? I could use a prompt style approach, where I give the an LLM Sections of the conversation and then ask it where it would put the Chunks. But that would require slicing up the conversation before hand since it won't all fit inside the context window. Or I could Feed it essentially line by line, giving it n-1 lines and then ask it if it should make a cut before this line? But that would require every line to run its on inference again which should take forever.
I was thinking of somehow using the logprobs to see if the AI would generate a chunk border, but that would require a specialized model.
Does anyone have any idea how I might do this?
